# Count Number of Triples in an array that are collinear

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was asked this Interview Question (C++,algos)and had no idea how to solve it.

Given an array say Arr[N] containing Cartesian coordinates of N distinct points count the number of triples (Arr[P], Arr[Q], Arr[R]) such that  P < Q < R < N and the points Arr[P], Arr[Q], Arr[R] are collinear (i.e lie on the same straight line).

Any ideas? What algorithm can I use for this?

Comment: I assume you're looking for something better than just brute force?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for worst case time complexity of O(N2log(N))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is probably not optimized, but its complexity is the one your interviewer requested.

First create a list of (a,b,c) values for each couple of points (N² complexity)
--> (a,b,c) stands for the cartesian equation of a straight line a*x+b*y+c=0
Given two points and their coordinates (xa, ya) and (xb, yb), computing (a,b,c) is simple.
Either you can find a solution to

```
ya=alpha*xa+beta  
yb=alpha*xb+beta

(if (xb-xa) != 0)
alpha = (yb-ya)/(xb-xa)
beta = ya - alpha*xa
a = alpha
b = -1
c = beta
```

or to

```
xa = gamma*ya+delta
xb = gamma*yb+delta
(you get the point)
```

The solvable set of equations can then be rewritten in the more general form

```
a*x+b*y+c = 0
```

Then sort the list (N² log(N²) complexity therefore N²log(N) complexity).

Iterate over elements of the list. If two sequential elements are equal, corresponding points are collinear. N² complexity.

You might want to add a last operation to filter duplicate results, but you should be fine, complexity-wise.

**EDIT** : i updated a bit the algorithm while coding it to make it more simple and optimal. Here it goes.

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct StraightLine
{
    double a,b,c;
    StraightLine() : a(0.),b(0.),c(0.){}
    bool isValid() { return a!=0. || b!= 0.; }
    bool operator<(StraightLine const& other) const
    {
        if( a < other.a ) return true;
        if( a > other.a ) return false;
        if( b < other.b ) return true;
        if( b > other.b ) return false;
        if( c < other.c ) return true;
        return false;
    }
};

struct Point { 
    double x, y; 
    Point() : x(0.), y(0.){}
    Point(double p_x, double p_y) : x(p_x), y(p_y){}
};

StraightLine computeLine(Point const& p1, Point const& p2)
{
    StraightLine line;
    if( p2.x-p1.x != 0.)
    {
        line.b = -1;
        line.a = (p2.y - p1.y)/(p2.x - p1.x);
    }
    else if( p2.y - p1.y != 0. )
    {
        line.a = -1;
        line.b = (p2.x-p1.x)/(p2.y-p1.y);
    }
    line.c = - line.a * p1.x - line.b * p1.y;
    return line;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> points(9);
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < 3 ; ++j )
        {
            points[i*3+j] = Point((double)i, (double)j);
        }
    }


    size_t nbPoints = points.size();
    typedef std::set<size_t> CollinearPoints;
    typedef std::map<StraightLine, CollinearPoints> Result;
    Result result;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < nbPoints ; ++i )
    {
        for( int j = i + 1 ; j < nbPoints ; ++j )
        {
            StraightLine line = computeLine(points[i], points[j]);
            if( line.isValid() )
            {
                result[line].insert(i);
                result[line].insert(j);
            }
        }
    }

    for( Result::iterator currentLine = result.begin() ; currentLine != result.end(); ++currentLine )
    {
        if( currentLine->second.size() <= 2 )
        {
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << "Line";
        for( CollinearPoints::iterator currentPoint = currentLine->second.begin() ; currentPoint != currentLine->second.end() ; ++currentPoint )
        {
            std::cout << " ( " << points[*currentPoint].x << ", " << points[*currentPoint].y << ")";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how I can go about computing a,b,c ?

Comment: Now all I have to do is code the whole thing.How do I convert the step  "Iterate over elements of the list. If two sequential elements are equal, corresponding points are collinear" into code? Can you explain the pseudocode?

Comment: Store the elements (a,b,c) with the points they refer to, as in struct CollinearElement{ int a; int b; int c; Point p1; Point p2; }; Create an operator < which can compare CollinearElement objects. If you don't know how to iterate over elements of a list, you probably need to read some standard library (STL) documentation.

Comment: I like this solution. I am pretty sure that the complexity can be improved to be output-sensitive, that is, the complexity will be better if more points are collinear. The way to do this is to use a modified version of merge sort, which removes duplicates as soon as they are encountered. I think the complexity would be O(max(N log N - sum (N_i log N_i), N)) where N_i is the number of duplicates of element i.

Comment: @Jorgen Fogh : My modified algorithm does that, a bit differently from what you described, though

Answer (score 4):

For the count of Collinear triplets, identify a line with any two points and then check whether a new line formed by any other two points might be coinciding or parallel and that needs to be taken care of while computing the collinear triplets.

To solve:

1. First, collect all points on a line using `Map<Line, Set<Point2d>>`
   as suggested in the question itself.
2. For triplets filter out those lines which have at least three points
3. Then compute nC3 for each of those add to global result.

> Code for the above problem below

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class CollinearTriplets {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Point2d A[] = new Point2d[8];
            A[0] = new Point2d(0, 0);
            A[1] = new Point2d(1, 1);
            A[2] = new Point2d(2, 2);
            A[3] = new Point2d(3, 3);
            A[4] = new Point2d(3, 2);
            A[5] = new Point2d(4, 2);
            A[6] = new Point2d(5, 1);
            A[7] = new Point2d(4, 4);

            System.out.println(countCollinear(A));
        }


        public static int factorial(int n) {
            int fact = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                fact = fact * i;
            }
            return fact;
        }

        private static int combinations(int n, int r) {
            return factorial(n) / (factorial(n - r) * factorial(r));
        }

        private static long countCollinear(Point2d[] points) {
            Map<Line, Set<Point2d>> lineToPoints = new HashMap<>();
            long result = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++) {
                    double slope = 0d, xIntercept, yIntercept; // Default slope paralell to y-axis
                    if (points[i].x == points[j].x) {
                        slope = Double.MAX_VALUE; // Horizontal slope parallel to x-axis
                    } else if (points[i].y != points[j].y) {
                        xIntercept = points[j].x - points[i].x;
                        yIntercept = points[j].y - points[i].y;
                        slope = yIntercept / xIntercept;
                    }
                    Line currLine = new Line(points[i], slope);
                    if (Objects.isNull(lineToPoints.get(currLine))) {
                        lineToPoints.put(currLine, new HashSet<>());
                    }
                    lineToPoints.get(currLine).add(points[i]);
                    lineToPoints.get(currLine).add(points[j]);
                }

            }
            for (Line line : lineToPoints.keySet()) {
                int size = lineToPoints.get(line).size();
                if (size >= 3) {
                    result = result + combinations(size, 3);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        /**
         * Line which contains the starting point and slope so that you can identify exact line
         * equals method is overridden to check whether any new line is coinciding or parallel
         */
        static class Line {
            Point2d point;
            double slope;

            public Line(Point2d point, double slope) {
                this.point = point;
                this.slope = slope;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object o) {
                if (this == o) return true;
                if (!(o instanceof Line)) return false;
                Line line = (Line) o;

                if (line.slope == this.slope)
                    return ((((double) (line.point.y - this.point.y)) / (line.point.x - this.point.x)) == this.slope);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                return Objects.hash(slope);
            }
        }

        static class Point2d {
            int x;
            int y;

            public Point2d(int x, int y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object o) {
                if (this == o) return true;
                if (!(o instanceof Point2d)) return false;
                Point2d point2d = (Point2d) o;
                return x == point2d.x &&
                        y == point2d.y;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                return Objects.hash(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
```

The time complexity for above code `O(N^2)` and space complexity is `O(N)`

Answer (score 2):

If it's 2 dimension points: 3 points (P,Q,R) are collinear if (P,Q), (P,R) define the same slope.

```
m = (p.x - q.x) / (p.y - q.y)  ; slope
```

Somehow you need to check all possible combinations and check, an efficient algo is trick as the first naive is N*(N-1)*(N-2)...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of 3 loops, whish is O(n³), precompute the slopes of all lines given by two points `Arr[P], Arr[Q]`. That's O(n²). Then compare these slopes.

You can improve that further sorting the lines by their slope during computation or afterwards, which is O(n log n). After that finding lines with the same slope is O(n).

But you may have to pay a price for that by implementing a data structure, when you want to know, which points are collinear.

I think the key point of an interview question is not to give the perfect algorithm, but to identify and discuss the problems within an idea.

**Edit:**

Brute force approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Point { int x, y; };
bool collinear(Point P, Point Q, Point R)
{
  // TODO: have to look up for math ... see icCube's answer
  return false; 
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Point> v;

  Point a;
  while (std::cin >> a.x >> a.y)
  {
    v.push_back(a);
  }

  int count = 0;
  for (int p = 0; p < v.size(); ++p)
  {
    for (int q = p+1; q < v.size(); ++q)
    {
      for (int r = q+1; r < v.size(); ++r)
      {
        if (collinear(v[p], v[q], v[r])) ++count;
      }
    }  
  }
  std::cout << count << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Trust me. the key point was not to discuss. I was asked to write a compilable program that was verified by an online judge for efficiency and correctness.

Comment: @user639309: Oh, it's about real code? Adjusted my answer for that.

Comment: thank you for the brute force approach. I would have still liked to find an optimal solution.

Comment: @user639309: Well ..., will I get that job then?

Comment: of course. However the online judge gave full marks to the optimal solution only..

Answer (score 2):

It's trivial to see that you can get all the pairs of points and their slope & y-intercepts in O(n^2) time. So the output is:

IndexB Slope Y-Intercept IndexA

Of course, we won't insert any entries where IndexA = IndexB.

Let's have this table indexed on (IndexB,Slope,Y), which forces our insert into this table as O(log(n))

After we fill out this table with new records (B',S',Y',A'), we check to see if we already have an element such that B'=A of the existing table and B!=A' of the new record (meaning we have a unique triplet) that matches the slope and Y-intercept (meaning collinear). If this is the case and A < B < B', increment the count by 1.

EDIT: One clarifying remark. We need to make sure that we fill this table "backwards" first, taking all the pairs that wouldn't satisfy A < B (< C). This ensures that they will exist in the table before we start testing for their existence.

EDIT: Wow my C++ is rusty... took a while.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

#define ADD_POINT(xparam,yparam) { point x; x.x = xparam; x.y = yparam; points.push_back(x); };

#define EPSILON .001

class line {
public:
  double slope;
  double y;
  int a;
  int b;

  bool operator< (const line &other) const{
    if(this->a < other.a)
      return true;
    else if(this->a==other.a){
      if(this->slope-other.slope < -EPSILON)
        return true;
      else if(fabs(this->slope-other.slope) < EPSILON){
        if(this->y-other.y < -EPSILON)
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      }else
        return false;
    }else
      return false;
  }

  line(double slope, double y, int a, int b){
    this->slope = slope;
    this->y = y;
    this->a = a;
    this->b = b;
  }

  line(const line &other){
    this->slope = other.slope;
    this->y = other.y;
    this->a = other.a;
    this->b = other.b;
  }
};

class point {
public:
  double x;
  double y;
};

int main(){
  vector<point> points;
  ADD_POINT(0,0);
  ADD_POINT(7,28);
  ADD_POINT(1,1);
  ADD_POINT(2,3);
  ADD_POINT(2,4);
  ADD_POINT(3,5);
  ADD_POINT(3,14);
  ADD_POINT(5,21);
  ADD_POINT(9,35);

  multiset<line> lines;
  for(unsigned int x=0;x<points.size();x++){
    for(unsigned int y=0;y<points.size();y++){
      if(x!=y){ // No lines with the same point
        point a = points[x];
        point b = points[y];
        double slope = (a.y-b.y)/(a.x-b.x);
        double yint;
        yint = a.y-a.x*slope;
        line newline(slope,yint,x,y);
        lines.insert(newline);
      } 
    }
  }

  for(multiset<line>::const_iterator p = lines.begin(); p != lines.end(); ++p){
    //cout << "Line: " << p->a << " " << p->b << " " << p->slope << " " << p->y << endl;
    line theline = *p;
    line conj(theline.slope,theline.y,theline.b,-1);
    multiset<line>::iterator it;
    pair<multiset<line>::iterator,multiset<line>::iterator> ret;
    ret = lines.equal_range(conj);
    for(it = ret.first; it!=ret.second; ++it){
      //cout << "  Find: " << it->a << " " << it->b << " " << it->slope << " " << it->y << endl;
      int a = theline.a;
      int b = theline.b;
      int c = it->b;
      if(a < b && b < c){
        cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }


  //cout << points[0].x << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Could you explain that first part to a humble mathematician like me to whom it is not trivial?

Comment: Yea..I did not get it either. Can you kindly skip the SQL and explain the algorithm?

Comment: @user639306 Let me know what part is confusing. Create the list, sort it, iterate over it O(n^2) looking to see if a corresponding element exists O(log(n))

Comment: It did not understand the part where you build the table/list.after we first compute the slope and y intercept of each pair of point

Comment: Wow my C++ is rusty... took a while. Edited in. Works under G++ in Linux with Wall. Floating point operations are PAINFUL!

Comment: superb! Let me try that on my compiler. I will also try to summarize the algorithm for my benefit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution tell if there is a better one,

Sort all the points according to the slope they make with the x axis or any other axis you want ( O(n* logn) ). Now all you have to do if go through the sorted list and find points which have same slope either inpositive or negative direction( this can be done  in linear time i.e. O(n) ) . Lets say you get m such points for one case then increment the answer by C(m,3)..

Total time depends on how good you implement C(m,3)

But asymptotically O(N logN)

Edit: After seeing icCube's comment  i realize that we cannot take any axis..so for the above defined algo taking the slope calculating point as one of the n points ( thus n times ) should be my best guess. But it makes the algorithm N*N*Log(N)

Comment: all possible ways of choosing 3 objects out of n.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: Also in this case C(n,3) should be a trivial constant time calculation as the 3 is always constant.. ( now that i think more deeply )..so C(n,3) = n*(n-1)*)(n-2) / 3*2*1

Comment: ok. How do I go about implementing C(n,3) ?  Did you mean m or n in C(n,3)?

Comment: nice, put write performance is not read performance (creating your sorted list will need time). Does one point define a slope ? -> you'll need N*(N-1) slopes don't you ?

Comment: @icCube , yes just take origin as you slope calculating point , colinear points will have same slope :).
user639309, yup you are right..edited

Comment: Sorry, don't thinks so -> (1,1), (2,3), (3,5) are colinear but slope is 1,2/3,3/5

Comment: I agree with icCube. I don't get how this algorithm can work.

Comment: Can some one explain me Benoit's algorithm?